#  Setting connection info using XQJ with Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, xquery

I am trying to submit XQuery queries to an Oracle 11g database through their XQJ API.

When I instantiate an oracle.xquery.xqj.OXQDataSource as explained in http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/oem/xquery-jdbc-325944.html, I can submit queries fine except that I haven't found how I can set up the server connection (server name, port, username, password, ...) info:

- This datasource claims that it doesn't support setting any property.
- It doesn't implement the data source constructor which takes a JDBC connection.
- I don't see any non standard method to set such info.
- When I try to access some random collection like collection("oradb:/foo") I just get an empty result set even when no server is running, suggesting that the driver doesn't even try to connect.

What have I missed and how can I set the server connection info?

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Charles Foster](http://xqj.net) I can answer to my own question: the XQJ implementation from Oracle is an old standalone version from January 2010 that is pretty useless and doesn't interact with Oracle databases.

Despite all the Oracle statements about XQJ, I haven't been able to find any client/server XQJ implementation (except one from DataDirect of course) and the way to submit XQuery queries to Oracle databases appears to be through JDBC, embedded in PL-SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in 12.

XQJ to run queries in Java:
http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDK/adx_j_xqj.htm#ADXDK99930

XQJ to run queries against the database:
http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDK/adx_j_xqjxdb.htm#ADXDK136